# How to create and export a vmware image using vmbuilder

Tags: 12.04, server, vmware, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I've been using vmbuilder to build kvm images as such:

```
vmbuilder kvm ubuntu \
    -v \
    --suite=precise \
    --libvirt=qemu:///system \
    --arch=amd64 \
    --cpus=2 \
    --mem=1024 \
    --swapsize=1024 \
    --rootsize=10240 \
    --flavour=server \
    --hostname=hostnamehere \
    --ip=X.X.X.X \
    --mask=X.X.X.X \
    --net=X.X.X.X \
    --bcast=X.X.X.X \
    --gw=X.X.X.X \
    --dns='X.X.X.X X.X.X.X' \
    --bridge=br0 \
    --mirror=http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu \
    --components='main,universe' \
    --addpkg=openssh-server,acpid \
    --user=username \
    --pass=password \
    --dest=/vmname \
    --tmpfs=-
```

However recently I had a request to build a VMWare image and although I have done such in the past using several VMWare tools I have recently read that this can also be achieved using vmbuilder, how would I go about creating a vmware image that I can give to my client and he can import to VMWare?

Also I'd need to add a second disk to the image, how can I add another vmdk?

Answer (score 1):

Although there are scripts available that can supposedly convert them, I don't trust them so I will show you the manual route here

---

The easiest way to do this is using QEMU directly. Power down the guest, then run the `qemu-img -O vmdk /path/to/guest/disk /path/to/new/disk.vmdk` command to convert the disk format (see below).

Next, use `virsh dumpxml vmname` to dump out an XML description of the guest.

Now, when creating a new VM in vSphere Client, just try and make the hardware at least as close as possible to the XML, and instead of creating a new disk image, just add the vmdk generated by the `qemu-img` command above.

This should do what you want

---

#### qemu Version Problems

Running these commands on Ubuntu 12.04 will give you no end of confusing version problems. In my experience, 1.5.3 gives good results. Follow the instructions [here](http://alistairchapman.com/blog/?p=117) (obviously changing the order and commands to match your situation), if you get stuck.